# MySQL query to get total percentage change

Tags: mysql, percentage, calculation

How to add a column of percent change (not [percentage points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentage_point)) in MySQL?

there is a table with column of changes in percents:

```
+---------+
| percent |
+---------+
|   -0.50 |
|    0.50 |
|    1.00 |
|   -0.20 |
|    0.50 |
|   -1.00 |
|   -2.00 |
|    0.75 |
|    1.00 |
|    0.50 |
+---------+
```

How to write a query that calculates a total percent change of a value for each row so the calculated row expresses its percentage change and  all previous rows of percentage change?.

expected result:

```
+---------+---------------+---------------+
| percent | nominal_value | total_percent |
+---------+---------------+---------------+
|   -0.50 |          0.50 |         -0.50 |
|    0.50 |          0.75 |         -0.25 |
|    1.00 |          1.50 |          0.50 |
|   -0.20 |          1.20 |          0.20 |
|    0.50 |          1.80 |          0.80 |
|   -1.00 |          0.00 |         -1.00 |
|   -2.00 |         -2.00 |         -3.00 |
|    0.75 |         -0.50 |         -1.50 |
|    1.00 |          0.00 |         -1.00 |
|    0.50 |          0.50 |         -0.50 |
+---------+---------------+---------------+
```

Where the `nominal_value` is an arbitrary value that was changed by `percent` so for the first row if the nominal value was 1.0 (100%) but was changed by `-0.50` (`-50%`) it resulted in nominal value `0.5` .

Then at the second row `percent` change was `+0.50` (`+50%`) so the nominal value was increased by half of it `0.5 => 0.75` but one can also say that it was just lowered by `-0.25` (`-25%`) from its original value since from `1.0` to `0.75` is a `-0.25` (`-25%`) of `1.0`.

That's exactly what I'm after a `total_percent` change, the `nominal_value` was just for the explanatory purpose and is not needed.

I'm using MySQL 8 so the query may use window functions / ranges etc.

here is the test table to replicate:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test
(
    percent DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL
)
ENGINE = InnoDB
;

INSERT INTO test (percent) VALUES 
(-0.50)
,(0.50)
,(1.00)
,(-0.20)
,(0.50)
,(-1.0)
,(-2.0)
,(0.75)
,(1.0)
,(0.50)
;
```

Comment: You need a PRIMARY KEY

Comment: I don't see how you can get from a nominal_value of 0 to a nominal_value of -2. Once something is 0 any percentage change on that value will give 0.

Comment: In the first and last lines of your data, `nominal_value` is 0.5. However in the first case `total_percent` is -0.5 and in the last case it is +0.5. How can this be?

Comment: @Nick for example you have a balance of $100 at your bank account and spend 100% of it so result was balance = $0, but because your account has loan capability you spend another $100 for shopping the same day so you end up with -$100 balance that is reflected by -200% of the initial balance amount and -100% going into dept from $0. Another example can be a change of value of sinus function that goes from -1 via 0 to +1 and back to -1 crossing 0. If you stopped at 0 then you would not be able to express rise or fall of it in percents over time.

Comment: @Jimmix ok, I get the negative value part, but how do you explain the different values of total_percent for the same value of nominal_value? (both 0 and 0.5 - the last two rows) have different total percent than for their first occurrences

Comment: @Nick you're right, thank you for pointing this out. I corrected expected result with other miscalculations as well.

Comment: @Jimmix ok, that agrees with what I expected the results to be.

Comment: @Strawberry can you evaluate why? I tested your answer with the `test` table without the `id` column and even removed `ORDER BY id` and still got the same result. Did you mean performance or there is another issue in case of not using `PRIMARY KEY`?

Comment: @jimmix if you don't have some way of uniquely identifying rows, then you don't really have a table. Without one, you may, accidentally, derive a result in line with your expectations, but that's just blind luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test;

CREATE TABLE test
( id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
, percent DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO test (percent) VALUES 
(-0.5)
,(0.5)
,(1)
,(-0.2)
,(0.5)
,(-1)
;

SELECT ROUND(@i:=(@i+(@i*percent)),2)n 
  FROM test
     , (SELECT @i:=1) vars 
 ORDER 
    BY id;
+------+
| n    |
+------+
| 0.50 |
| 0.75 |
| 1.50 |
| 1.20 |
| 1.80 |
| 0.00 |
+------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Answer (score 2):

This query will give you the results you want. It uses two CTEs, the first which simply adds a row number to the data, and the second, recursive CTE which generates the `nominal_value` values from the current `percent` and the preceding `nominal_value` (where preceding is defined by row number). Finally `total_percent` is computed from the `nominal_value`.

**Note**

To make this (and any similar) query work reliably, there has to be a `PRIMARY KEY` that the first CTE can have its results ordered by. In the demo I have added an `AUTO_INCREMENT INT` column `id` for this purpose.

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
  SELECT percent, ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS rn
  FROM test
  ORDER BY id),
cte2 AS (
  SELECT 1 + percent AS nominal_value, rn
  FROM cte
  WHERE rn = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT CASE WHEN nominal_value = 0 THEN percent
              ELSE nominal_value + percent * ABS(nominal_value)
              END,
         cte.rn
  FROM cte
  JOIN cte2 ON cte2.rn = cte.rn - 1
  )
SELECT percent, nominal_value, (nominal_value - 1) AS total_percent
FROM cte2
JOIN cte ON cte.rn = cte2.rn
```

Output:

```
percent nominal_value   total_percent
-0.5    0.5             -0.5
0.5     0.75            -0.25
1       1.5             0.5
-0.2    1.2             0.2
0.5     1.8             0.8
-1      0               -1
-2      -2              -3
0.75    -0.5            -1.5
1       0               -1
0.5     0.5             -0.5
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hprSbmGURxPDg4EoYLAq65/2)

Comment: it worked well on data provided with the question, however when testing at bigger data set got this error `ERROR 3636 (HY000): Recursive query aborted after 1001 iterations. Try increasing @@cte_max_recursion_depth to a larger value.` Is inevitable to use recursion in query. Perhaps due to lack of an index?

Comment: @Jimmix yes, you need to use a recursive query because of the iterative process of creating the `nominal_value` values. But there is no harm in setting that variable large enough to cover all the rows in your table.

Comment: I would like to avoid to set this variable high enough because if I understand reason behind it properly it is a protection against a close to infinite run of badly written queries. I tried to rewrite your query, but failed. Could using combination of LAG() / Temporary Table / variables be solution?

Comment: @Jimmix you can always set an execution time limit. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursion-limits. The issue with using variables is that they are deprecated in MySQL 8.0 and will be removed in a later version.

Comment: If the `test` table had an additional column with unique dates that are PRIMARY KEY then would it be possible to write a query that gives the same result but does not use variables nor recurrence?

Comment: @Strawberry interesting - why does the presence of the index change everything? To be fair though, your query only works because you've added an auto_increment primary key to it, and this query would work fine with that too...

Comment: That's EXACTLY my point!! Without a PRIMARY KEY, this solution (any solution) is entirely dependent upon the whim of the server.

Comment: @Strawberry have updated my answer to make that point and add a primary key to the demo. Was suffering from lack of coffee earlier in the day which is why it took so long to get your point. Thanks.

Comment: @Nick changed [--cte-max-recursion-depth](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_cte_max_recursion_depth) to max value (4300M rows), should be enough for a while :) Just wondering if there is any switch to disable that restriction at all cause I haven't found any.

Comment: @Jimmix I don't believe there is any way to turn it off. Setting it to 0 precludes any recursion at all and negative values are not allowed. Still, a llimit of 4300M should keep you going...

Comment: @Jimmix just to keep your options open, I've posted an alternate solution using a stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

This is a small variation of the accepted answer due to the fact OP edited post and added additional rows of data and wanted result after accepted ans. was posted and accepted:

> Query:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test;

CREATE TABLE test
( 
 id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
 , percent DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO test (percent) VALUES 
(-0.50)
,(0.50)
,(1.00)
,(-0.20)
,(0.50)
,(-1.0)
,(-2.0)
,(0.75)
,(1.0)
,(0.50)
;

SELECT 
    percent,

    CASE @i 
        WHEN 0 THEN ROUND(@i:=(@i+(percent * 1)),2) -1
        ELSE ROUND(@i:=(@i+(percent * ABS(@i))) ,2) -1
    END total_percent

FROM 
    test
    , (SELECT @i:=1) vars         
ORDER 
    BY id;
```

> Result:

```
+---------+---------------+
| percent | total_percent |
+---------+---------------+
|   -0.50 |         -0.50 |
|    0.50 |         -0.25 |
|    1.00 |          0.50 |
|   -0.20 |          0.20 |
|    0.50 |          0.80 |
|   -1.00 |         -1.00 |
|   -2.00 |         -3.00 |
|    0.75 |         -1.50 |
|    1.00 |         -1.00 |
|    0.50 |         -0.50 |
+---------+---------------+
10 rows in set, 3 warnings (0.00 sec)
```

Note that accepted answer stops calculations after reaching zero nominal value and then no matter the percentage change makes no difference and nominal value is the same = 0. For some cases this might be the right approach. For others here's this one that continues calculation through zero or @Nick answer in case you use MySQL 8.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate way to compute this data is using a stored procedure. The advantage of this approach is that it doesn't require a recursive CTE or variables, but the disadvantage is that it can be tricky to use the results (for example in a `JOIN`). This procedure creates a temporary table to store results before returning them; that table could be preserved instead of being `DROP`ped at the end of the procedure if further processing was needed. As with the other answers, this approach requires the data to have a `PRIMARY KEY` to guarantee consistent results.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE total_percent()
BEGIN
  DECLARE nominal_value DECIMAL(10,2) DEFAULT 1;
  DECLARE this_percent DECIMAL(5,2);
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE p_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT percent FROM test ORDER BY id;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE p (percent DECIMAL(5, 2),
                            nominal_value DECIMAL(10, 2),
                            total_percent DECIMAL(10, 2));
  OPEN p_cursor;
  compute: LOOP
    FETCH p_cursor INTO this_percent;
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE compute;
    END IF;
    IF nominal_value = 0 THEN
      SET nominal_value = this_percent;
    ELSE
      SET nominal_value = nominal_value + this_percent * ABS(nominal_value);
    END IF;
    INSERT INTO p VALUES (this_percent, nominal_value, nominal_value -1);
  END loop;
  SELECT * FROM p;
  DROP TABLE p;
END //
DELIMITER ;

CALL total_percent();
```

Output:

```
percent  nominal_value   total_percent
-0.5     0.5             -0.5
0.5      0.75            -0.25
1        1.5             0.5
-0.2     1.2             0.2
0.5      1.8             0.8
-1       0               -1
-2       -2              -3
0.75     -0.5            -1.5
1        0               -1
0.5      0.5             -0.5
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hprSbmGURxPDg4EoYLAq65/4)

Comment: Great to see :) I will check how it works, funny thing you've mentioned problems with JOINs because exactly now Im working with your ans using CTEs and do JOINs with other tables :) What's so tricky using JOINs with procedure like this?

Comment: @Jimmix If you want to use the stored procedure, give the temporary table a more useful name and remove the `SELECT *` and `DROP` statements from the end. Then you can use the temporary table in other queries.

Comment: @Jimmix  For `JOIN`ing with the CTE, wrap that last `SELECT` up as another CTE i.e. `, cte3 AS (SELECT percent, nominal_value, (nominal_value - 1) AS total_percent
FROM cte2
JOIN cte ON cte.rn = cte2.rn)` and it will be reasonably easy to use in a `JOIN` statement later in your query.