# MySQL 5 to 8 query migration (rewrite) - variables within expressions

Tags: mysql, variables, migration, warnings

I have a MySQL 5 query that generates desired output but with warnings on MySQL 8.

The query I have with variables:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test;

CREATE TABLE test
( 
 id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
 , percent DECIMAL(5,2) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO test (percent) VALUES 
(-0.50)
,(0.50)
,(1.00)
,(-0.20)
,(0.50)
,(-1.0)
,(-2.0)
,(0.75)
,(1.0)
,(0.50)
;

SELECT 
    percent,

    CASE @i 
        WHEN 0 THEN ROUND(@i:=(@i+(percent * 1)),2) -1
        ELSE ROUND(@i:=(@i+(percent * ABS(@i))) ,2) -1
    END total_percent

FROM 
    test
    , (SELECT @i:=1) vars         
ORDER 
    BY id;
```

Is one of the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55289067/mysql-query-to-get-total-percentage-change/55291411)
 and produces desired output:

```
+---------+---------------+
| percent | total_percent |
+---------+---------------+
|   -0.50 |         -0.50 |
|    0.50 |         -0.25 |
|    1.00 |          0.50 |
|   -0.20 |          0.20 |
|    0.50 |          0.80 |
|   -1.00 |         -1.00 |
|   -2.00 |         -3.00 |
|    0.75 |         -1.50 |
|    1.00 |         -1.00 |
|    0.50 |         -0.50 |
+---------+---------------+
10 rows in set, 3 warnings (0.00 sec)
```

but with 3 warnings:

> Warning | 1287 | Setting user variables within expressions is
> deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Consider
> alternatives: 'SET variable=expression, ...', or 'SELECT expression(s)
> INTO variables(s)'.

How to use:

> alternatives: 'SET variable=expression, ...', or 'SELECT
> expression(s) INTO variables(s)'.

and change this query so it does not generate warnings on MySQL 8?

Is there any general guide or set of recommendations/examples on how to rewrite properly a query from MySQL5 to MySQL8 so there are no warnings on MySQL8?

I expect that in general from MySQL 5 to MySQL 8 variables are not the only ones that need to be rewritten, so what else?

---

Please note that the question is not about using [CTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html), but rewriting usage of variables from MySQL 5 to MySQL 8 query that does not produce any warning or error.

Also this question is solely about producing expected result at DB server, perfectly with just one query (if possible)

Comment: There was a solution provided in the previous question you asked, using a recursive CTE query. Other than that, if you want an iterative solution without recursion, you should just fetch the uncalculated values from the database and do the calculations iteratively in your application code.

Comment: @BillKarwin the question isn't duplicate because it specifically asks for a way of applying `alternatives: 'SET variable=expression, ...', or 'SELECT expression(s) INTO variables(s)'.` not for using CTEs, + how to `rewrite properly a query from MySQL5 to MySQL8` - what are incompatibilities?. Linked question with ans. is just for the background of a particular sql query used as an example. Fetching raw data and calculating it outside DB and inserting it back is against the whole point of doing data processing at large scale by using DB itself but an option when dataset is small (not my case)

Comment: I will reverse the close vote, but the alternatives are: (1) use a CTE as shown, or (2) fetch all the results into your application and calculate the values progressively using code, not SQL.

Comment: `SET ..` or `SELECT .. INTO` won't help you to solve this task. You either need iteration or a multiplication aggregate function. Both are not available in SQL. But iteration can be replaced by a recursion. So an answer is already given in your other question. And you are still ignoring comments from the other question. You have no PK and no column for the order. So actually there is no answer possible.

Comment: @Paul Spiegel If the test table had been changed so It had PK and column for order would the answer be possible?

Comment: @Bill Karwin You ware right and first with your comment. Please paste as the answer "The alternatives are: (1) use a CTE as shown, or (2) fetch all the results into your application and calculate the values progressively using code, not SQL." to the question and I'll accept it so you can collect the bounty.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The alternatives are:

1. Use a CTE as shown in the answers to your previous question.
2. Fetch all the results into your application and calculate the values progressively using code, not SQL.

Comment: I came looking for an answer to the same problem. You and the OP might understand this answer in the context it was asked, but after the event I don't know what a CTE is, and I now have to go hunting for the OPs previous question to see if it helps. Sadly, this 'answer' is not particularly useful.

Comment: @ReddHerring So you think it is appropriate to downvote a correct answer because _you_ don't understand it?

Comment: No - I think it appropriate to downvote an answer because it isn't an answer